# Python. DB-API(PyMySQL, PostgreSQL, ...). Cursors(cursor = connect.cursor()). One cursor on all queries, or one cursor per query?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, cursor

For example **PyMySQL**. How will cursors be used more correctly?

**Option 1**:

```
connect = pymysql.connect()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

**Option 2**:

```
connect = pymysql.connect()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.close()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

Those. Can I use a single cursor for all queries, or create a new cursor each time for a new query?

And, if you use one cursor for one type of query with different data? For example, **option 3**:

```
connect = pymysql.connect()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id_1 = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO city(name) VALUE('%s')', ('Moskow',))
last_id_2 = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.close()

cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result_1 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM city')
result_2 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

Which option is better/more correct to use (and in terms of performance too)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Repeat it for Each Time. You Only need it one time..

// Creating the Connection

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='pwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id_1 = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO city(name) VALUE('%s')', ('Moskow',))
last_id_2 = cursor.lastrowid

cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result_1 = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM city')
result_2 = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.close()
```

To apply the changes to DB for Insert or Update Query you should add the below code snippet also.

```
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: Those. Create only one cursor and work through it? For example, a web server that always works: at the start we create a cursor, and all the time the server works -
 through this cursor we fulfill all the requests. It will be correct?